# Como instanciar uma classe com métodos abstratos em C#

Tags: c#

Em java podemos implementar métodos abstratos ao instanciar determinada classe

```
Thread threadA = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i =0; i<2; i++){
                System.out.println("This is thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    }, "Thread A");
```

Gostaria de saber se isto é possível em C#, implementar um método abstrato em ultima hora,
e se possível gostaria de um exemplo

Answer (score 8):

É possível sim, você precisa apenas criar a declaração do método de forma abstrata e então na classe que deseja adicionar a implementação usar o "override".

```
public abstract class MinhaClasseBase
{
    public abstract void MeuMetodo(string parametro);
}

public class MinhaClasse : MinhaClasseBase
{
    public override void MeuMetodo(string parametro)
    {
        Console.Write(parametro);
    }
}
```

Caso sua intenção seja criar métodos anônimos para iniciar uma thread, então você poderia montar assim:

```
var thread = new Thread(t =>
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("Dentro da thread. [{0}]", i);

}) { IsBackground = true };
thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, através de um objeto chamado `Action Delegate`:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Por exemplo:

```
class Teste
{
    public static void MinhaAcao<T>(T numero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Numero = " + numero);
    }

    public static Delegate CriarAcao(Type type)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof (Teste).GetMethod("MinhaAcao").MakeGenericMethod(type);
        var actionT = typeof (Action<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionT, methodInfo);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CriarAcao(typeof (int)).DynamicInvoke(5);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```